# How can a cigarette be held in position by a cheek?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Would somebody rewrite the following sentence for me in a way that is easier to understand?  It's from the Wikipedia article on the [Taman Shud Case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taman_Shud_Case).

> ... a half-smoked cigarette was on the right collar of his coat held
>   in position by his cheek.

I don't know how a cigarette can be held by a cheek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe the [context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taman_Shud_Case): this is the description of a corpse discovered on the beach.

Presumably the "fashionable European grey and brown double-breasted coat" was disarranged, so that the collar was somewhat higher on the neck than if the decedent were standing; the head had fallen to the right, resting to some extent on the collar; and the cigarette was wedged between the collar and the cheek.

Answer (score 0):

This would be by tilting the head to the right and lifting up the right shoulder until they meet. He could be holding it there while he does something else with his hands, but it would be difficult to not get smoke in his eyes; presumably he's holding it there while he rummages around in his pockets looking for a lighter. This is similar to how people hold telephones when they need their hands free to do something else with.

Comment: @snailplane I could not see that context in the question.

Comment: That is a good point, and I've edited the question to add it.

Comment: I hope the O.P. will learn to add such context to future questions, because it's often invaluable to understanding meaning. I can ask the community: What does _Mary had a little lamb_ mean? and get lots of answers about a schoolgirl and lamb, but then when I reveal that Mary is my new girlfriend, and we went to have dinner at a fancy restaurant last night, the perspective changes in a hurry. Reading the question as originally posed by the O.P., "holding it like a telephone" is what would have jumped into my mind, too.